# How to create thumbnail images just to show not to save using Yii2 Imagic

Tags: yii2, imagick

I am using yii2 imagick to manage the images. I have already done with the codes to upload the images. But when displaying there is some image width*height proportion issue. That is why I am using yii2 imagick.
In imagick there is an option to create a thumbnail image to the folder with the uploaded image, like the code below

```
Imagick::open('./image.jpg')->thumb(200, 200)->saveTo('./thumb.jpg');
```

But I don't want to save the thumbnail I need just to display.for that I just did like

```
<img src="<?=Imagick::open('./image.jpg')->thumb(200, 200)?>">
```

But I am getting some errors. Is there any other way to do this. I just want to display thumbnail images that fit the container.

Comment: This really looks like a bad idea. `src` attribute in `img` tag expects URL to image, so throwing thumbnail object here won't work. Even if you use `data:` and base64-encoded image, it will be really inefficient in terms of cache and overall performance (you need to generate and send thumbnail on every page view).

Comment: If you are using `tpmanc/yii2-imagick` that library only has method for saving image into file and it's `$image` property is private so even extending that class won't help in implementing the `data:` url approach. You can bypass that with [`ReflectionClass`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) but that's usually not a good idea. The best approach would be either creating a thumbnail when image is uploaded or (if the disk space is an issue) create an action that would generate and send thumbnail with proper cache headers.